# Flutter MissingPluginException with several plugins

Tags: flutter

I've been using a handful of flutter plugins recently. Many worked perfectly, but I stumbled across frustrating errors several times, generally resulting in giving up the plugins.

Here is the last one I got, with [schedule_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/schedule_notifications#-readme-tab-) :

```
E/flutter (24758): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (24758): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getIconResourceId on channel schedule_notifications_app)
E/flutter (24758): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter (24758): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24758): #1      _MyAppState._getIconResourceId (<my path>/sandbox/lib/main.dart:67:40)
E/flutter (24758): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24758): #2      _MyAppState.initState (<my path>/sandbox/lib/main.dart:24:7)
E/flutter (24758): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3751:58)
E/flutter (24758): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3617:5)
E/flutter (24758): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2907:14)
E/flutter (24758): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2710:12)
E/flutter (24758): #7      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:857:16)
E/flutter (24758): #8      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:828:5)
E/flutter (24758): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:17)
E/flutter (24758): #10     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2222:19)
E/flutter (24758): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:773:13)
E/flutter (24758): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:662:7)
E/flutter (24758): #13     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:704:7)
E/flutter (24758): #14     main (<my path>/sandbox/lib/main.dart:8:16)
E/flutter (24758): #15     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
E/flutter (24758): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
D/libGLESv2(24758): DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : <my package>
D/libGLESv1(24758): DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : <my package>
D/ViewRootImpl(24758): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl(24758): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

There are many examples of similar questions on SO and GitHub (*see the end of my post*), but the only thing ever suggested to fix them is "use `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, `flutter packages get` and then `flutter run`". **Sometimes it may be enough, but not always** - in my particular case, I still get the exact same error.

Noticeably, if I clone the whole GitHub repository of the plugin and run the example from within this directory, it does work well. But if I try to re-create the example project, it does not, so I take it I'm missing something, but what ?

**Here are the steps I followed to re-create the example :**

1. Create a new Flutter project in Android Studio
2. Add the dependency `schedule_notifications: ^0.1.8 in pubspec.yaml`
3. Click on the Flutter commands `Packages get` and `Packages upgrade` in Android Studio
4. Click on the popup `Get packages` in Android Studio when it appeared
5. Paste the code from https://github.com/serralvo/schedule_notifications/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart in my `main.dart` file
6. Change the line `import 'package:schedule_notifications_example/time_picker.dart';` into `import 'time_picker.dart';` to resolve the error I got from Android Studio
7. Create a file `time_picker.dart` next to `main.dart` and paste in it the code from https://github.com/serralvo/schedule_notifications/blob/master/example/lib/time_picker.dart
8. Execute the project in Android Studio and get the aforementioned error
9. Launch the Flutter console and go in the directory of my project
10. Execute the commands `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, `flutter packages get` in the console
11. Execute the command `flutter run` in the console and still get the same error

**So, what is going on exactly ? What could produce this behavior with some plugins, for some developers or some projects ? What am I doing wrong ?**

**Examples of similar questions :**

- [MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360060/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-init-on-channel-plugin)
- [Flutter: google_sign_in plugin MissingPluginException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189458/flutter-google-sign-in-plugin-missingpluginexception)
- [MissingPluginException while using plugin for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459272/missingpluginexception-while-using-plugin-for-flutter)
- [Flutter Test MissingPluginException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357053/flutter-test-missingpluginexception)
- [Flutter MissingPluginException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430532/flutter-missingpluginexception-error)
- [Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared\_preferences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had removed this line(by mistake) from `MainActivity.kt` (inside the `onCreate` hook)

```
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
```

Probably a mistake, but cost me a lot of time. Hope helps someone.

Comment: I have the same issue when I went to the MainActivity.kt, I had:

    package com.example.komerso
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
    import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
    
    class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
        override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        }
    }


Do i missing something?

Comment: This fixed my issue, it seems that if we override "configureFlutterEngine" , this method needs to be explicitly called in the end of it.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of `MainActivity.kt` please?

Answer (score 7):

When you add new plugin, you need to re-build the application, the hot re-start doesn't build the application and your newly added is not included in your project unless built again.

Answer (score 5):

After spending 12 hrs of a continuous effort to solve this in a flutter android project... finally solved - inspired by "@rahulserver" solution as follows

Just merge the following code in "MainActivity.java"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this.getFlutterEngine());
}
```

Note: The MainActivity extends FlutterActivity

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I'm posting what I found in case it could help somebody in the future. *But I'm still interested in further explanations.*

So, to make the [schedule_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/schedule_notifications) plugin work, I had to open the file `MainActivity.java` in the [example project](https://github.com/serralvo/schedule_notifications/blob/master/example/android/app/src/main/java/co/serralvo/schedulenotificationsexample/MainActivity.java). There, I noticed some lines which were not present in my own project :

```
    MethodChannel methodChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "schedule_notifications_app");
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
        if (methodCall.method.equals("getIconResourceId")) {
          result.success(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
      }
    });
```

When I copied and pasted those lines in my own `MainActivity.java` file (with the right imports), my project finally worked.

You'll notice that in `main.dart`, we have these lines :

```
static const _platform = const MethodChannel('schedule_notifications_app');
```

and

```
iconResourceId = await _platform.invokeMethod('getIconResourceId');
```

Those are linked to the new lines in `MainActivity.java`. That's where the issue came from.

**Performing those steps result in making the plugins work, but I'm unsure if it is good or awful practice.** And in case it really is what we are supposed to do, I must say it is **quite not obvious** ! I think that **at least the plugins installation docs should explain it**.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and took me a while to understand why it’s happening.
The solution is simple, just kill the application and run a fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. After adding any plugin statement in `pubspec.yaml` file, you need to do a `flutter packages get` command. Stopping running app, uninstalling then rebuild worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by modifying the Android build a little.

1. Goto `android/app/build.gradle`
2. Add the following lines:

```
android {

   // other config stuff here

   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release

           // Add these 2 lines
           minifyEnabled false   
           shrinkResources false
       }
   }
}
```

I think this prevents some build optimisations, which break the plugin registration somehow...